# Posted data on form submit

Tags: woocommerce

Hello everyone i have a question.

I have a checkout form which looks like this:

[image]

Using woocommerce these are the billing fields. I was wondering in which file this data is posted/sent. I assume there is a file that POSTS all the filled in data. which file is this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below path is form-billing form file path. Please follow this path:

> wp-content->plugins->woocommerce->templates->checkout->form-billing.php